# Xcode 6 Interface Builder "cannot open compiled nibs" error, FiksuSDK

Tags: ios, interface-builder, cocoapods, xcode6

I have an app that runs great in Xcode 5, using CocoaPods.

When I open the app on Xcode 6 and hit build and run, I get four errors from the FiksuSDK about compiled nib files.

On the side, it states that I do not have permission to view it, but tapping on it shows the error: "The document "FMVerifyViewController.nib" could not be opened. Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs." I don't directly call any of these nib files, however it's possible that the Facebook API does.

Screenshots attached.

I've tried removing the Pods directory, deleting derived data, updating pods and restarting Xcode. Nothing.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Screenshots:
[image: Interface Builder NIB Postprocessor Error]
[image: Cannot Open Compiled Nibs]

Comment: Does this only happen in Xcode 6 or even Xcode 5? When you browse the source directories in Finder, do you find `.nib` files? They are compiled `.nib`'s and you can't edit them. If the CocoaPod contains the wrong files, it's not your fault and you can't fix it

Comment: No, this builds and runs fine under Xcode 5. I have also tried with the Xcode 6 beta2, and still having the same issue.

Comment: What files do you find in the Finder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages unfortunately are misleading because it's not a permissions problem and the nibs are valid. It appears that because they are provided as *symlinks* to the resource files, Xcode complains.

Fiksu just released a new version of their SDK where this issue is fixed. (look for version 4.3.1)"

Disclosure: I am a Fiksu Employee

Comment: Changed this to the correct solution as it doesn't require removing elements, and is supported by Fiksu.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the "Build Settings" of your Project and set "Strip NIB Files" in "Interface Builder NIB Postprocessor - Options" to NO - worked quite well for me :)

Comment: In Xcode 10 the option is called "Flatten Compiled Storyboard Files"

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a very good answer, but I had this same problem and in order to keep developing (until this gets figured out), I just removed those 4 nibs from the project. Just go to the project file, select the target you're building against, go to the "Build Phases" tab, and delete those 4 nibs from the "Copy Bundle Resources" section. Your project should build and run fine for the time being (I haven't encountered any negative effects to not having these nibs). By the way I think they're from the Fiksu SDK, not the Facebook SDK.