# How do I recover a storyboard in xcode?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a little bit of a situation here. A few days ago, I accidentally deleted my storyboard, so immediately went into my trash and dragged the storyboard back into the project. Everything worked fine. But then I just emptied my trash and the storyboard no longer appears to be in my project; the storyboard file is showing up red and when I click on it, nothing loads. To my dismay, I thought all was lost so I started building a new storyboard and connecting the classes, outlets and actions.

I then went to build the project on the simulator, and it's building with the OLD storyboard. I thought it might just be loading it from memory so I deleted the app on the simulator and built the project again. Same thing again. So then I built it to my iPhone and somehow the old storyboard is still there even though I can't find it anywhere in my project.

What's going on here? Does this mean I'll be able to recover my storyboard?

Also, when I open the project inspector and go to Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, and right click on Storyboard.storyboard, and click show in finder, It shows my new storyboard.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - There is a place in `Derived Data` with following path:

```
/Users/<Your user name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Your App Name>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app Name.app>
```

Browse to that location.

2 - On your .app file, right click -> Show Package Contents.

3 - In resulting directory list, browse the folder `Base.lproj`. Under that you are likely to find your old storyboard.

If you have done `Delete Derived Data` from XCode organizer, you are not likely to find anything up here. But fortunately, XCode doesn't delete it twice against your own wishes.
So try your luck.

Comment: I think I found the file. But xcode is saying that Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs.

Comment: OK, refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110342/xcode-6-interface-builder-cannot-open-compiled-nibs-error-fiksusdk

Comment: I can see that this is old question but I am having the same problem now with Xcode 6.3.1 and the link above dose not seem so helpful I was wondering can there be other solution. To be more exact when I copied the Main storyboard from the path above the main storyboard is named Main.Storyboardc

Comment: I am having the same problem. But when i paste that path it is showing that the folder doesn't exist. Can anyone help?

Comment: Derived Data folder can now be reached via XCode->Windows menu->Projects->Select your project->Click the arrow icon at the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem in Xcode 7.

But when I copy and paste it from `Derived Data`. I got

> "Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs"

So If you delete storyboard by reference. First, check your project folder (using the Finder). If it's there, you can drag it back into your project in Xcode, or you can use the “Add Files to …” menu option. that file is work perfectly.