# Connecting interface builder with compiled nibs

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nib, xcode-storyboard

I have accidentally deleted my main storyboard. Now I am trying to use the main storyboard from this path:

> Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/.

I found here a file named Main.storyboardc which I suppose is my main storyboard but when I am trying to compile it (with this new Main.storyboardc) I am having an error saying Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs. 
I know this question is discussed before but I didn't find anything helpful
Furthermore I am using Xcode 6.3.1 and this discussion was not very healpfull [Xcode 6 Interface Builder "cannot open compiled nibs" error, FiksuSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110342/xcode-6-interface-builder-cannot-open-compiled-nibs-error-fiksusdk)

Comment: You know Xcode has `git` support built-in, right?

Comment: I just searched a bit about git, and saw that I have not used it in this project

Comment: Based on the fact that this question exists, I could have told you that.  Consider this lesson learned?  [ALL YOUR SOURCE ARE CONTROL BY US](http://importblogkit.com/2015/04/source-control/)